# Checking a list of logins on dropbox

Tags: authentication, dropbox

I have a strange request for a project - we have a text file containing a list of login credentials for Dropbox for around 10 users. I have to validate their credentials automatically and notify the users if login fails with their credentials.

I've looked at the dropbox API, but that uses OAuth, which requires the user to manually fill in credentials, but that doesn't do the trick for me.

Is there a way for me to check if a bunch of logins? I've looked at the DropboxUpload repository on github, but it works fine for single user logins, but fails to achieve what I want when it comes to checking the same thing for multiple users.

Any help/leads on how I should go about proceeding with this would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropbox webpage to check user credentials doing normal login/logout but in an automated way.
To create a "bot" which will login and logout and check if credentials are correct you can use Selenium.

Selenium is a framework for testing web page ui but it can also be used to create automated checker/tester/bot for what you need.

It is also possible to setup selenium in a such way that it will use renderless browser engine so no browser will be visible during test/check. This also speeds up the process of testing.

I hope this will help you if you'll not find any better way and can be used as a final solution since it is not the best way to check credentials